# Escaping quotation marks in python string

Tags: python, string, escaping

I'm using `subprocess` to call a program within python and I'm passing a string to it, which can contain quotation marks.

This is the piece of code that is giving me troubles

```
import subprocess
text = subprocess.Popen("""awk 'BEGIN { print "%s"}' | my_program """ % sentence, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

When `sentence = "I'm doing this"` I get the following error message

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I guess this has to do with the way quotes are escaped in python and linux. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: try `sentence = "I\'m doing this"`. you're confusing `awk` because there's a quote in your quoted awk expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're confusing `awk` and underlying shell because there's a quote in your quoted awk expression. First part is equivalent to:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "I'm doing this"}'
```

Which is incorrect, even in pure shell.

Quickfix, escape the quotes in your sentence:

```
text = subprocess.Popen("""awk 'BEGIN { print "%s"}' | my_program """ % sentence.replace("'","\\'"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Proper fix: don't use `awk` at all just to print something, just feed input to your subprocess:

```
text = subprocess.Popen(my_program, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error = text.communicate(sentence.encode())
```

(and you can get rid of the `shell=True` in the process)

Last point: you seem to have trouble because `my_program` is some program plus arguments. To pass a command such as `aspell -a` you can do:

```
my_program = "aspell -a"
```

or:

```
my_program = ['aspell','-a']
```

but *not*

```
my_program = ['aspell -a']
```

which is probably what you've done here, so Python tries to literally execute the program `"aspell -a"` instead of splitting into program + argument.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but I get this error when I try to replace `my_program` with what is should be (`"aspell -a"`) `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aspell -a'`.

Comment: You want to avoid a shell and run `Popen(['aspell', 'a'])` instead of putting the first argument as string.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess/36008455#36008455

Comment: Incidentally, avoiding these quoting issues is another good reason to avoid `shell=True`.

Comment: @tripleee actually it works when passing a _string_ with spaces in it. Which _doesn't_ work is passing a _list_ of parameters but with incorrect splitting: `['aspell -a']`

Comment: Yeah, with the additional caveat that I guess the last one might actually work on Windows.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(["dir /B"],shell=True)` fails on windows. So no, if that's what you meant. Windows is _evil_ but even evil has standards :)